# react-router browserHistory removeListen?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I subscribe to route changes with

```
browserHistory.listen(fn)
```

but how can I unsubscribe?

I have tried assigning to `listen` `null`, but it complains about not being a function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return from `listen` is a function that will unsubscribe the listener when called. So just save it for later:

```
var unlisten = browserHistory.listen(fn)

// ...some time later...
unlisten()
```

Comment: What is fn()? what you passing on fn(), can you please provide an example?

Comment: @BeckiD It's whatever function you want to run for the history listener whenever a history change happens.